# Efficiently snap to vertices in threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I wanted to make a snapping functionality to snap to my mesh vertices. I experimented with several solutions.

One solution is to add `THREE.Sprite` instances for all vertices in my scene and then using a `rayCaster` to decide whether there is a `snap` point in the `intersects` array. It works pretty well; here [is a fiddle with a demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/esuox2q1/).
The idea is to hide the sprites in the final solution so they won't be rendered, but my scenes are pretty big so it would still mean adding lots of sprites to my scene (for every vertex one so possibly thousands of sprites) to detect snap points with my `rayCaster`.

```
var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObject(scene, true);
var snap = null;
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var index = 0;
    var intersect = intersects[index];
    while (intersect && intersect.object.name === 'snap') {
        snap = sprite.localToWorld(sprite.position.clone());
        index++
        intersect = intersects[index];
    }
    if (intersect) {
        var face = intersect.face;
        var point = intersect.point;
        var object = intersect.object;
        mouse3D.copy(point);
    }
}
if (snap) {
    renderer.domElement.style.cursor = 'pointer';
} else {
    renderer.domElement.style.cursor = 'no-drop';
}
```

---

I also thought of an alternative solution by doing the math using results from the `rayCaster`. That solution is demonstrated [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/k3d93wvs/). 
The idea here is to test all `vertices` from the geometry of the `object` (mesh) that is intersected and then check whether the `distance` between the intersect `point` and those `vertices` from the geometry is smaller then the snap `threshold`.

```
var intersects = rayCaster.intersectObject(mesh, true);
if (intersects.length > 0) {
    var distance, intersect = intersects[0];
    var face = intersects[0].face;
    var point = intersects[0].point;
    var object = intersects[0].object;
    var snap = null;
    var test = object.worldToLocal(point);
    var points = object.geometry.vertices;
    for (var i = 0, il = points.length; i < il; i++) {
        distance = points[i].distanceTo(test);
        if (distance > threshold) {
            continue;
        }
        snap = object.localToWorld(points[i]);
    }
    if (snap) {
        sphereHelper.position.copy(snap);
        sphereHelper.visible = true;
        renderer.domElement.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
        sphereHelper.visible = false;
        renderer.domElement.style.cursor = 'no-drop';
    }
}
```

The sad thing is that in the second solution snap will only work when the mouse is moved from the surface of the intersected object towards a vertex. In case the mouse is moved from outside the object (so there is no intersection) the snapping won't work. In that respect the first solution with sprites is much more usable...

My question, am I overcomplicating things and is there a better/simpler/more efficient way to do this? Any suggestions for alternative approaches are welcome.

Comment: I assume you want to snap on a Click? If so, I can help you, but I want to make sure before I answer. ALSO, what angle would you like to view when you snap to? If it's the cube, it's obvious, but if you have a plane of verticies, it's not as obvious what angle you want to view it from

Comment: Yes, that will be in the end the idea. But adding that is not the problem, I am more struggling with how to get find the correct vertex to snap to in an efficient way. The model will have 1000+ vertices and I somehow need to calculate which vertex is within the threshold distance of my mouse.

Comment: Raycaster.intersects[0] should always return the closest object that it intersected

Comment: @Rush2112 I understand that, I am not sure what you want to point out with your comment. Maybe my question is not clear enough, I will edit my post a bit...

Comment: Sorry, I just realized what you wanted. I've built cubes using vertex objects, but I forgot that it would chose the whole cube, ergo all vertices. I understand now. Sorry for the other comments. Since I've dug myself this far, I will look into the correct solution

Comment: Could you build an octree or kd tree for each object's vertices (assuming the sprites method) and raycast through that to find your vertex? Alternatively, using the second method, create a box or sphere that's slightly larger than the mesh that you can intersect with so the raycast doesn't have to hit the mesh necessarily? I'm not too familiar with three.js but hopefully this helps.

Comment: @meepzh this [threeoctree](https://github.com/collinhover/threeoctree) looks indeed very promising. I didn't know about this octree solution. Too bad it is only supporting up to r60, but I have at least something new to consider. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into @meepzh his suggestion of using an octree and made the following solution using [this **threeoctree** repository from github](https://github.com/collinhover/threeoctree). The `THREE.Octree` class did not solve all my problems *out-of-the-box* so
I added custom method `findClosestVertex` to the `THREE.Octree` class that can be used like this.

```
var snap = octree.findClosestVertex(position, radius);
```

`snap` is `null` in case no vertices within the `radius` of `position` and returns the closest point (`THREE.Vector3`) in world space otherwise.

I made a Pull-Request [here on github](https://github.com/collinhover/threeoctree/pull/12) for the new method.

**[Here is a demo in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/3ahg0hmg/)**