# THREE.js - Trying to get nearest point (Vector 3) of object from click-generated Vector 3

Tags: javascript, three.js, game-engine

I'm working on a point-and-click test game and have made a ton of progress through research and finding other stack overflow answers about this-or-that, but this is the first time I can't seem to find anything related to my question.

My plan is to implement PatrolJS into my project for pathfinding, and it seems like I shouldn't have any problem getting it working after this issue is solved.  I have my environment as well as some NPC characters in my scene.  I have the mouse interaction in 3d space able to select and store data about what is clicked on.  I am able to move my character to the click positions.  I believe my problem will come in registering clicks into the pathfinding area.

Here a visual representation of my question:

[image]

Here, you can see my environment simplified down to one color, as well as the area I am currently defining for my navmesh area.  The player will be able to click anywhere on the 3d environment/NPC's etc to interact with/view/use elements in the environment. That clicking works already, returning me with the point in 3d space that the mouse/ray intersects with, and giving me any information about those elements clicked on that I have defined.

What I need some guidance with is, how can I get returned the most nearby point on the separate navmesh object to what was clicked in the environment object(s)?  Say I click on some part of one of the tables.  I want to be able to find the absolute closest Vector 3 point on the navmesh object.  That way, if someone interacts with elements off of the navigable area, I can still define an endpoint and feed that into PatrolJS.

Comment: I can provide help, but it will need pictures/illustrations that I can't provide at the moment because I'm at work. I'll try to see if I can do that when I get home

Comment: Check my somewhat related question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128896/efficiently-snap-to-vertices-in-threejs), I think you will find some useful things in there...

Comment: Can the player only move on the 2D plane? This would reduce it to a 2D problem, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given a mesh made out of `n` triangles and a point `p` you can find the closest point from the mesh to `p` using brute force in `O(n)`, the algorithm is as follows

- For each triangle `t` that belongs to the mesh

  - project `p` onto the plane defined by `t`, let `proj` be this point
  - if `proj` lies on `t` then it's the closest point to `p`, store the distance from `proj` to `p`
  - if `proj` lies outside the triangle then compute the closest point to `proj` for each of the 3 sides of the triangle, store the distances from each of these points to `p`
- The overall answer is the point whose distance is closest to `p`

### [THREE.js Demo](http://codepen.io/maurizzzio/pen/pERqxV?editors=0010)

Comment: Thank you!  Using your suggestion, I was able to get exactly the behavior I was looking for.  The demo really helped out a lot, too.  Thanks for taking the time. Anyone else that needs a similar result, check this answer^.